# Magento: How to search for products in category by name in mini search

Tags: php, magento, search, zend-framework

I want to search for categories in Magento's mini search form.

But not with a Dropdown with a list of categories.
Just when I type a name of a category in the mini-search form it should display products out of this category.

Example:

I search for "pullover", and the result should include any products with the category pullover even if the search string ("pullover") doesn't match with title and description and also all products which would match the normal search filter and which are NOT in category pullover

---

### UPDATE 1

I think I have to hook into the Method `prepareResult()` of the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext`

there is a block, where a $select object is defined:

```
$select = $adapter->select()
            ->from(array($mainTableAlias => $this->getMainTable()), $fields)
            ->joinInner(array('e' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
                'e.entity_id = s.product_id',
                array())
            ->where($mainTableAlias.'.store_id = ?', (int)$query->getStoreId());
```

Does anyone know how am I able to search for categories too?

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Your question is not clear enaough. Do you want to remove magento's default functionality and then adding your search product by category name? You need to override ResultController of catalogsearch module and add your code. In your code load category collection and fetch it's products and append in search collection.

Comment: I added an example to my question

Comment: Are you looking for both category and product search? if only category search then create your own module otherwise override catalogsearch core module.

Comment: I want to override catalogsearch core module, but I don't find the method where I have to hook in...

Answer (score 0):

I tried much to realize this.
This is the first "hacky" solution for my question:

I override `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext->_prepareProductIndex()`

and there between the test for in_stock and the return I inserted something like:

```
    $query = "
        SELECT `cv`.`value`
        FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `cv`
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp`
        ON (`ccp`.`category_id` = `cv`.`entity_id`)
        WHERE `ccp`.`product_id` = " . $this->_getReadAdapter()->quote($productData['entity_id']) . "
        AND `cv`.`store_id` = " . $this->_getReadAdapter()->quote($queryStoreId) . "
        AND `cv`.`attribute_id` = (
            SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'name' AND `entity_type_id` = 3
        );
    ";

    $categories = array();

    foreach ($this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($query) as $result)
        $categories[] = html_entity_decode($result['value']); // HACK!!!

    $index['categories'] = $categories;
```

The next step is to put this into a helper function and abstract the table names.

Maybe there will be someone who finds this helpful :-)